# How many combinations in this 4 digit pin

Tags: combinatorics

The pin code is

- 4 digits  between 0-9
- Can be entered in any order e.g 1234 4231 1324 will all work
- has no repeating numbers

writing them all out i have 194 codes to try.

however the math gives me 210 codes
5040 different non repeating codes
24 ways to write each code

5040/24 = 210

have i overlooked something?

Thanks

Comment: The number of codes is the number of ways to **choose** $4$ digits from $10$. This is $\binom{10}{4}$, which is $210$. As to the $194$, it can be surprisingly difficult to make a list that is complete and has no repetitions.

Comment: A couple of years behind but I just found this. Do banks even have a requirement that PINs cannot have repeating numbers? Which way would provide more possible combinations?

Answer (score 2):

You’re 100% correct.

There are 10 possible numbers for the first digit, and then you can’t use that number again, so 9 for the second, and using the same logic, 8 for the third and 7 for the fourth. That means there’s $10\times 9\times 8 \times 7 = 5040$ combinations. Divide this by the number of ways to order each one, 24, and you get 210, as you said.

Answer (score 0):

The math you have done is sound, thus 210 is correct. The error should be in writing them out, make sure you haven't missed any.